# Python 2.7 line 5 i am having invalid syntax

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

Been looking at this for a while and cant seem to figure out why I'm receiving invalid syntax on the if statement.

```
   number = 6
   if number > 5 and < 9:
        print  “Yes”
   else:
        print “No”
```

Comment: Looks like you are beginning your journey in coding. Checkout https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp. Tutorials would be great help in the begining then after you can start reading https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: You might have got some downvotes but take it positively. Try to find answers by following some tutorials; searching more rigorously.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help. Just learning and do not quite understand the etiquette of this website yet. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the variable name in your second comparison:

```
if number > 5 and number < 9:
     blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 2):

You have made an error in declaring your if statement. Your program does not know what should be smaller than 9. The correct syntax for your problem would be:

```
if 5 < number < 9:
```

or

```
if number > 5 and number < 9:
```